# send json file using http.post meteor and then get it via http.get

Tags: web-services, meteor, http-post

I need to send a json format data using http.post to a url. Wrote the following code to test on local

```
 var postData = {
"channelName" : "Number Theory1",
"startDate" : "2017-07-22T06:29:35.681Z",
"endDate" : "2017-08-22T06:29:35.681Z"
}
HTTP.call('POST', 'http://localhost:3000', {
   data: postData 
 }, (error, result) => {
 if (error) {
   console.log('we are getting this error:' + error);
 } else {
    console.log('POstres : ' + result);
 }
 }); 
function extractProcessData(data){
   console.log('function called! : ' + data);     ##data here should be var processData but it prints undefined
}
function confirmDataReceived(data) {
  HTTP.get('http://localhost:3000', function(err, res){
  // confirmation error
  if(err){
    console.log('error ' + err);
  }
  // confirmation success and process data
  else{
    console.log('data : ' + data + res)    ## data here prints as undefined whereas according to me, it should contain thevar postData ##
    extractProcessData(data) //call function to process data
  }
});
}
var postRoutes = Picker.filter(Meteor.bindEnvironment(function(req, res) {
 if (req.method == "POST"){
   console.log('req : ' + req.method + " " + req.body)
   confirmDataReceived(req.body);
 }
 return true;
 // return req.method == "POST";
}));;;
```

Its not working. I guess the issue is with http.post data syntax. Is it the proper way to send data via http.post? I hope my http.get method via picker function is correct.

Any help would be appreciated.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

```
var postData = {
    "channelName" : "Number Theory1",
    "startDate" : "2017-07-22T06:29:35.681Z",
    "endDate" : "2017-08-22T06:29:35.681Z"
}
HTTP.call('POST', 'http://localhost:3000', {
  data: postData 
}, (error, result) => {
  if (error) {
       console.log('we are getting this error:' + error);
  } else {
        console.log('POstres : ' + JSON.stringify(result));
  }
});
```

Comment: not working. posting the whole scenario for better understanding

Comment: why, is there an error in my code related to that? afaik, my routes and dependencies are correct

Comment: have you checked/called the function in which you have coded http call ?

Comment: All the code is on server side. As soon as the server starts, http.call.post is fired